# Strongloop loopback-component-storage + angularjs file upload

Tags: angularjs, loopback

I created a Container model and connected it to an S3 bucket which all works well.  I am trying to upload a file using Angular, using the service file generated with `lb-ng`.

If I do `Container.upload({container: 'testbucket'}, {file: file})` call will fire but nothing uploads.  Am sure I have just got the params wrong but cannot find any example of the angular library being used, and the official example at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage uses a different angular uploader to handle the upload, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm also stuck on the same thing

Comment: There's no solution it seems, you have to use a 3rd party uploader like in their example  :(